# Custom User Model Django TypeError: create_user() missing 1 required positional argument: 'username'

Tags: python, django

I am creating a custom User model and I am getting an error when I create my super user for the first time. Any advice, please. I would ideally like to user BOTH my `username` or `email` for verification interchangeably, but this may be a question for another day.

I started initially with email as my `username_field` but changed after a while. Please, can someone provide guidance, please? I have posted my `models.py` file which sits inside the accounts app.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
    AbstractBaseUser,
    BaseUserManager
)


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email,
                    username,
                    password=None,
                    is_active=True,
                    is_staff=False,
                    is_admin=False,
                    is_client=True,  # anyone registered can be a client
                    is_partner=False

                    ):
        if not username:
            raise ValueError("Unique username is required")
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("User must have an email address")
        if not password:
            raise ValueError("Password is required")
        user_obj = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_username(username)
        )
        user_obj.set_password(password)  # change user password
        user_obj.username = username
        user_obj.email = email
        user_obj.staff = is_staff
        user_obj.client = is_client
        user_obj.partner = is_partner
        user_obj.admin = is_admin
        user_obj.active = is_active
        user_obj.save(using=self._db)
        return user_obj

    def create_staff_user(self, username, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(
            username,
            password=password,
            is_staff=True
        )
        return user

    def create_partner_user(self, username, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(
            username,
            password=password,
            is_partner=True
        )
        return user

    def create_client_user(self, username, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(
            username,
            password=password,
            is_client=True
        )
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, username, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(
            username,
            password=password,
            is_staff=True,
            is_admin=True
        )
        return user


class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=255)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, max_length=255)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)  # can login
    staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)  # staff user non super
    admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)  # superuser
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'  # username
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []  #['full_name']

    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.username

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.username

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.staff

    @property
    def is_partner(self):
        return self.partner

    @property
    def is_client(self):
        return self.client

    @property
    def is_admin(self):
        return self.admin

    @property
    def is_active(self):
        return self.active
```

The error from shell is as below

```
PS C:\Users\User\Desktop\protectandserve> python manage.py createsuperuser
Username: xxxxxxxx
Password:
Password (again):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.1-py3.7.egg\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.1-py3.7.egg\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.1-py3.7.egg\django\core\management\base.py", line 316, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.1-py3.7.egg\django\contrib\auth\management\commands\createsuperuser.py", line 59, in execute
    return super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.1-py3.7.egg\django\core\management\base.py", line 353, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.1-py3.7.egg\django\contrib\auth\management\commands\createsuperuser.py", line 184, in handle
    self.UserModel._default_manager.db_manager(database).create_superuser(**user_data)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\protectandserve\accounts\models.py", line 68, in create_superuser
    is_admin=True
TypeError: create_user() missing 1 required positional argument: 'username'
PS C:\Users\User\Desktop\protectandserve>
```

Comment: Create user requires two parameters, `email` and `username`, here you only call the fuction with `username`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look in your code:

```
def create_superuser(self, username, password=None):
    user = self.create_user(
        username,
        password=password,
        is_staff=True,
        is_admin=True
    )
    return user
```

you are not setting `username`. It should be:

```
def create_superuser(self, username, password=None):
    user = self.create_user(
        username = username,
        password=password,
        is_staff=True,
        is_admin=True
    )
    return user
```

Further, you can try this for both email and username register:

```
def create_superuser(self, username=None, email=None, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(
            username = username,
            email = email.
            password=password,
            is_staff=True,
            is_admin=True
        )
        return user
```

Comment: Try my examples.

Comment: What happened @project_kingz?

Comment: Your solution worked without the additional REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username', 'email' ]

Comment: the solution by @aman kumar seems sensible but because 'username' is in USERNAME_FIELD it cant be placed in REQUIRED_FIELDS

Comment: Great!! Congratulations!! Can you then accept it as the answer so, the question can be close and later others can find it easily. P.S. don't forget to upvote.

Comment: please edit your response first as the REQUIRED_FIELDS part I havent been able to prove

Comment: What do you need in the Required_Fields? If you use this you have to provide both username and email address. In my example I have given none option as a default if one of them is not provided it will be stored as none but I assume in your model the user field does not have null = true, blank = true fields .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182653/discussion-between-rarblack-and-project-kingz).

Answer (score 1):

if you need both fields as required fields

```
REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username', 'email' ]
```

Comment: @project_kingz This is not the answer to the question. It doesn't solve the error, just additional. Therefore, it can be upvoted but not accepted as the answer to the question.

Comment: @Rarblack it will slove now when you run the creatsuperuser command it will ask for the email too

Comment: He is not setting any email address in the createsuperuser code. So, this will solve nothing. Also, if he still provides username will get the same error.

Comment: by setting USERNAME_FIELD= 'username' and REQUIRED_FIELDS=['email'] I got it to work , but now I am unable to connect to my admin although superuser is created successfully ??

Comment: Because you are providing email but it is set in nowhere. Basically, you are just setting a password. Try to create the user with a username.